# Debugging Entity Framework Model Building Exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I'm hitting the error

> Sequence contains more than one matching element

after upgrading EF from 6.1.0-beta1 to the latest 6.1.3 in my ASP.NET MVC project.

Stack trace is included below, and since it shows the exception is thrown during model building, I assume there's an issue with my model that was OK in the previous EF version (my model hasn't changed), but since my model is rather extensive I've been searching high and low for a way to get any information about the specific table/class where the problem occurs.

I've tried enabling debugging .NET framework code in VS to see if I could reach the exception in the debugger, but it fails to download the debug symbols for Entity Framework. I've tried downloading the source, and building it to point to the .pdb file, but it wouldn't accept it.

I've even tried changing the references to my own build of EF, but got an error because it wasn't signed.

How can I find out which entity/class/table has the problem?

UPDATE: Through trial and error, it turns out the error appears when updating from Entity Framework version 6.1.0 to 6.1.1.

> [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element]
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable'1 source, Func'2 predicate) +4380333
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.<>c__DisplayClass4a.b__47(ForeignKeyBuilder fk) +178
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each(IEnumerable'1 ts, Action'1 action) +130
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.ForeignKeyPrimitiveOperations.RemoveAllForeignKeyConstraintsForColumn(EntityType table, EdmProperty column, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping) +155
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.EntityMappingConfiguration.CleanupUnmappedArtifacts(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType table) +1312
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.EntityMappingConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection'1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, EntityType entityType, EntityTypeMapping& entityTypeMapping, Boolean isMappingAnyInheritedProperty, Int32 configurationIndex, Int32 configurationCount, IDictionary'2 commonAnnotations) +1719
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigureTablesAndConditions(EntityTypeMapping entityTypeMapping, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection'1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) +155
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection'1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) +105
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) +361
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo) +434
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +55
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +62
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy'2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +627
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.Initialize() +53
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.GetEnumerator() +15
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() +53
>   System.Collections.Generic.List'1..ctor(IEnumerable'1 collection) +375
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable'1 source) +58
>   Scanboat2014.Repositories.ScanboatAdRepository..ctor() in C:\Users\Martin\Source\Repos\Scanboat\Scanboat2014\Repositories\ScanboatAdRepository.cs:26
>   Scanboat2014.Controllers.HomeController..ctor() in C:\Users\Martin\Source\Repos\Scanboat\Scanboat2014\Controllers\HomeController.cs:18

Comment: Looks like a duplicate foreign key name in your model.

Comment: Thanks gert-arnold, that helps me narrow the search, but as mentioned my model is pretty comprehensive, so tough to find out where, and strange that it would only be an error in 6.1.1 and not in 6.1.0. Commenting out blocks of code would be terrible since removing an entity would require lots of references throughout the code to be commented out as well. I was hoping to somehow get debugging information to figure out where this duplicate occurs.